Is it possible to "undeclare" a script block in HTML?
I'm developing a web app which dynamically loads and unloads the contents of a a <div> block, which acts as a sort of page system.
The problem
The problem starts with the fact that I sometimes include some <script> blocks in the loaded page, scripts which are only used for that page.
This causes a problem when I load another page which happens to have a function or a constant that shares It's name with one from a previously loaded script.
What I tried
In attempt to fix this, I made a simple test page in which I simply wanted to unload a <script> block.
My attempt is as follows:


<!--Script to unload-->
<div id="content">
    Script is in this block

    <script>
        async function ShowMessage() {
            alert("Hello!");
        }
    </script>
</div>

<!--Call function from script-->
<button class="test-button" onclick="ShowMessage()">
    Test script
</button>
<br>
<br>

<!--Code which unloads script-->
<button class="test-button" onclick="DeleteData()">
    Delete block with script
</button>
<script>
    async function DeleteData() {
        const content = document.getElementById("content");

        // Destroy the script element
        const scriptList = content.querySelectorAll("script");
        const convertedNodeList = Array.from(scriptList);
        convertedNodeList.forEach(scriptItem => {
            console.log(scriptItem);
            scriptItem.remove();
        });

        content.outerHTML = "";
    }
</script>



Final notes
Maybe "undefining" a const is not possible, in which case I could use variables or just not use any sort of global constants. But at least the scripts I would like to find a proper way to unload them.
Also I would like to be able to make this method work, rather that using something like a <iframe>, since with this method I have more control over the content being loaded.
This question only applies to a <script> block, not a externally loaded JavaScript file.

This issue plagued web development about 15 years ago. Which script would trample over what else. We have modules to fix this. First it was just closures, then fully fledged module systems built on the back of those, then with ES6 modules went in as a core feature. Yet pretty much any build toolchain has some step to handle modules - whether old school, or ES6 ones. Why do you want to go to the pre-module days? Why not just properly isolate your code so it doesn't stomp all over global scope?

@VLAZ I'm not exactly sure how to isolate the code. I have barely worked with modules beforehand.

Well when a script is parsed, it becomes part of the JavaScript "realm" of the page. There's no way to tell the browser "please undo that <script>" because it doesn't (and can't, really) keep track of what each script does.

Simplest solution, avoid globals
